# How to update payment status inside an order?

Tags: 8, commerce, payment-gateways

I am trying to update order status and payment status depending upon the value we get in a variable called $payment_status.  I am able to update order status but I am unable to update payment status inside that order. I am getting an error "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.
Error: Class 'Drupal\commerce_order\Payment\Payment' not found" The code I used is as follows:-

```
//update order status based on payment status
  $order = \Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\Order::load($order_id);
  // dpm($order);
  if($payment_status === 'payment.captured' ){
    $order->set('state', 'completed' );
    $order->save();
    $payments = \Drupal\commerce_order\Payment\Payment::loadByProperties(['order_id' => $order_id]);
      foreach ($payments as $payment)
      {
        $payment->setState('completed')->save();
      }
  }
  else{
    $order->set('state', 'pending' );
    $order->save();
  }
```

How to solve this?

Comment: I guess you could do it \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
->getStorage('commerce_payment')
->loadByProperties([
 'order_id' => [$orderid],
  ]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change the code from

```
 \Drupal\commerce_order\Payment\Payment::loadByProperties(['order_id' => $order_id]);    
        TO        
 \Drupal::entityTypeManager() ->getStorage('commerce_payment') ->loadByProperties([ 'order_id' => [$orderid], ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like below:

```
$payments = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('commerce_payment')->loadByProperties(['order_id' => $order_idS]);
```